# Convert an array of binary numbers to corresponding integer

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators

How to convert an array of binary numbers that have only 1 and 0 to a corresponding number? Like

```
var binArray  = [1, 0, 1, 1] ;
output = 11;
```

I know I need to use bitwise operators `>>` `<<` somehow, but I don't how.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parseInt()` alongwith base or radix argument like this:

```
> var binArray = [1, 0, 1, 1]
> binArray.join('')
"1011"
> parseInt(binArray.join(''), 2)
11
> parseInt("101", 2)
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a [left shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift) `<<`.

```
                     return
     r       a     dec     bin
------  ------  ------  ------
     1       0       2      10
     2       1       5     101
     5       1      11    1011
```

```js
var binArray = [1, 0, 1, 1],
    output = binArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return (r << 1) | a;
    });

console.log(output);
```

ES6

```js
var binArray = [1, 0, 1, 1],
    output = binArray.reduce((r, a) => (r << 1) | a);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to pass `0` as initial value, you can just omit it.

Comment: Thanks for this, could you explain me what means (r << 1) | a?

Comment: it shifts the value of `r` one bit left, that means, the value is like multiplied with two and then a bitwise or is performed with `a`.